# Saving Data To Firebase with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, casting, firebase

I copied the examples from firebase.com but I'm getting an error:
[image]

I can't get my code to recognize my text dictionary and save it.

Comment: Please add your code rather than a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 1):

So I believe you are referencing a modified version of the following version from the [firebase ios docs:](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-setvalue)

Consider declaring the `newText` variable as `AnyObject` like so:

```
var newText: AnyObject = ["test1": gracehop]
```